# ASP.Net MVC 4 EditorFor DateTime not prepopulating in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A datetime input field in the edit view of a controller isn't loading the current value from the model when browsed in Chrome.  The page loads with a time editor field, but the value is empty.  The intent is to display the time editor, and have it be prepopulated with the current value on page load.  I've searched around, and most of the fixes involve applying a format string, but this doesn't work for me.  I'd like some help on getting this to work.  Thanks.

#### View

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BeginTime)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeginTime)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)
</div>
```

#### Model

```
public class WorkInterval
    {
        public int WorkIntervalID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime BeginTime { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `EditFor`, try to use `TextBoxFor`. See below code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BeginTime,new{@id="Datepicker",@Value = Model.BeginTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime,new{@id="Datepicker",@Value = Model.EndTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")})
```

Comment: This works, except I would like to keep the editor with controls for adjusting the time.  I realize the way I described what editor I wanted to use was vague, so I went ahead and edited it.  Thanks for your time and sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: If you add jquery Datepicker for these TextBox, you can control these times. I added Datepicker in the Textbox, you can try it.